# Novo projeto em MEAN Stack

Tags: node.js, angularjs

Algum tempo atrás li o livro de MEAN da Casa do código, fiz toda a aplicação e depois cheguei a fazer curso da Alura também de MEAN, porém os *frameworks* atualizaram e estou querendo fazer um novo projeto em MEAN.

Queria saber qual seria o setup básico para configurar o MEAN, pois parece que não usa mais o Express ou algo assim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## MEAN

A stack MEAN é um acrônimo das tecnologias **M**ongo, **E**xpress, **A**ngular.js e **N**ode.js. Então o MEAN utiliza o express, caso contrário será outro acrônimo.

Para iniciar a stack atualizada do MEAN é recomendado utilizar o generator [angular-fullstack](https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack)

Para instalar:

`npm install -g yo gulp-cli generator-angular-fullstack`

para iniciar (escolha as tecnologias de sua preferência)

`yo angular-fullstack`

## Outras Stacks

Com o tempo e mais experiência em javascript, se sentirá livre para utilizar outras tecnologias e outras stacks como o MERN, que ao invés do angular.js, utiliza o react.js. Ou ainda (este é o mais interessante) o [generator-ng-fullstack](https://github.com/ericmdantas/generator-ng-fullstack).

Com o tempo é comum você montar sua própria stack pois terá necessidades e objetivos diferentes.

Comment: Maravilha, vou dar uma olhada nesse generator do angular, mas eu queria montar o projeto do 0 para conhecer os plugins e tals.

Comment: Faça isso. Você deve demorar umas 2 semanas para montar e intender um projeto.